# how do i evaluate a conditional in an argument javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

Im trying to call a method that will add or subtract 1 from a given span based on whether they already have it favorited or not (basically they favorite/unfavorite a resource and a little counter says "8 people favorited this" will be updated)

I want to write it short hand in the statement though rather than writing all kinds of if statements before the function, i thought there may be a fancy smarter way to do it.

this code obviously doesnt work but it should give you a gist of what im trying to say

```
updateFavoritesSpan( this, if ($(this).hasClass('starred')) 1 );
```

declaration:

```
function updateFavoritesSpan(element, isFavorite) {
    $(element);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this:

```
updateFavoritesSpan( this, $(this).hasClass('starred') );
```

**[`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass)** always return Boolean value, if found then `true` else `false`.

There is also another one called **[`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is)** and it will use like:

```
updateFavoritesSpan( this, $(this).is('.starred') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hasClass returns boolean so you can pass it directly

```
updateFavoritesSpan( this, $(this).hasClass('starred'));
```